# Using R to download SAS file from ftp-server

Tags: r, download, ftp, rcurl

I am attempting to download some files onto my local from an ftp-server. I have had success using the following method to move .txt and .csv files from the server but not the .sas7bdat files that I need.

```
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "ServerName"
userpwd <- "User:Pass"
tsfrFilename <- "/filepath/file.sas7bdat" 
ouptFilename <- "out.sas7bdat"

# Run #
## Download Data
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, tsfrFilename)
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)

## Create File
fconn <- file(ouptFilename)
writeLines(data, fconn)
close(fconn)
```

When I run the getURL command, however, I am met with the following error:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string:
```

Does anyone know of any alternative way which I can download a sas7bdat file from an ftp-server to my local, or if there is a way to alter my code below to successfully download the file. Thanks!

Comment: Try `getBinaryURL()` instead. That's safer with binary data.

Comment: `download.file()`?

Comment: @MrFlick I was able to use the function you mentioned to get past that particular step. However the writeLines function gives me the error message "invalid 'text' argument"

Comment: Use `writeBin()` rather than `writeLines()` like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426359/downloading-large-files-with-r-rcurl-efficiently). sas7bdat files are binary, not text. They don't have "lines".

Comment: @MrFlick of course. Unfortunately I am getting an error here too, "WriteBin() can only write to a binary connection", otherwise my code is set up the same as I have it above

Answer (score 6):

As @MrFlick suggested, I solved this problem using `getBinaryURL` instead of `getURL()`. Also, I had to use the function `write()` instead of `writeLines()`. The result is as follows:

```
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "ServerName"
userpwd <- "User:Pass"
tsfrFilename <- "/filepath/file.sas7bdat" 
ouptFilename <- "out.sas7bdat"

# Run #
## Download Data
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, tsfrFilename)
data <- getBinaryURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)

## Create File
fconn <- file(ouptFilename)
write(data, fconn)
close(fconn)
```

Alternatively, to transform the read data into R data frame, one can use the library `haven`, as follows

```
library(haven)
df_data=  read_sas(data)
```