# Attempting to download files from SFTP using R

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm trying to implement R in the workplace and save a bit of time from all the data churning we do.

A lot of files we receive are sent to us via SFTP as they contain sensitive information.

I've looked around on StackOverflow & Google but nothing seems to work for me. I tried using the RCurl Library from an example I found online but it doesn't allow me to include the port(22) as part of the login details.

```
library(RCurl)
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "hostname"
userpwd <- "user:password"
tsfrFilename <- "Reports/Excelfile.xlsx"
ouptFilename <- "~/Test.xlsx"

url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, tsfrFilename)
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)
```

I end up getting the error code

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
embedded nul in string:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this will save us loads of time!

Thanks,

Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a similar situation here: [Using R to download SAS file from ftp-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856937/using-r-to-download-sas-file-from-ftp-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm no expert in r but there it looks like getBinaryUrl() worked instead of getURL() in the example given.

Hope that helps
M

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two packages, `RCurl` and `rcurl`. For `RCurl`, I used successfully keyfiles to connect via sftp:

```
opts <- list(
    ssh.public.keyfile = pubkey, # file name
    ssh.private.keyfile = privatekey, # filename
    keypasswd <- keypasswd # optional password
) 
RCurl::getURL(url=uri, .opts = opts, curl = RCurl::getCurlHandle())
```

For this to work, you need two create the keyfiles e.g. via putty or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I too was having problems specifying the port options when using the `getURI()` and `getURL()` functions.

In order to specify the port, you simply add the port as `port = ####` instead of `port(####)`. For example:

```
data <- getURI(url = url,
               userpwd = userpwd,
               port = 22)
```

Now, like @MarkThomas pointed out, whenever you get an encodoing error, try `getBinaryURL()` instead of `getURI()`. In most cases, this will allow you to download `SAS` files as well as `.csv` files econded in `UTF-8` or `LATIN1`!!