# Import File from FTP to R

Tags: r, import, ftp

Want to download a csv-file from FTP-Server to R (it would be best to have the file as a dataframe in R).

Get an error-message when trying to download a csv-file from FTP-Server to R (which is local in my Mac).

```
url = "ftp://ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/"

download.file(URL,"test.csv", credentials = "xxx:yyyy")
```

Last query leads to:

```
Error in download.file(URL, "test.csv", credentials = "xxxyyy",  : 
unused arguments (credentials = "xxx:yyyy")
```

Comment: In the documentation of the function `download.file()` I can not see a parameter `credentials=`.

Comment: you are right. my mistake, I mean  'download_ftp_file'. Found it here: [https://rdrr.io/github/skgrange/threadr/man/download_ftp_file.html]. My Problem now: Can not find a package with that function, even not with '?download_ftp_file'

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019200/6574038

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/skgrange/threadr/f/README.md

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you get this error message because function [`download.file()`](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Accessing-files-on-password-protected-FTP-sites-td2286862.html) has no argument named `credentials`.

I would try to pass the credentials as discussed [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Accessing-files-on-password-protected-FTP-sites-td2286862.html):

```
url = "ftp://username:password@ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/test.csv"
download.file(url, destfile = "test.csv")
```

If you want to load the file into an R data.frame, you could try something like this:

```
library(RCurl) 
url <- "ftp://ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/test.csv"
text_data <- getURL(url, userpwd = "username:password", connecttimeout = 60)
df <- read.csv(text = text_data)
```

Comment: thx, but it results in message: `trying URL "ftp://username:password@ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/test.csv" Content type 'unknown' length 10 bytes`. Its a csv file with 1 columns and 3 rows with numbers from 1 to 3

Comment: Applying `url = ftp://username:password@ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/`results in message `trying URL '"ftp://username:password@ftppath/www_logs/testfolder/`. Ist this an error message? How can I transfer my download to an R-Objekt, e.g. in a `dataframe`?

Comment: I edited my answer and hope the code works in your case.

Comment: Hi Franziska, it nearly works perfectly and I state your response as "correct answer". One issue remains: the first row does not contain `1` but `<ef><bb><bf>1` in `df`. I also added `header = FALSE`, otherwise first row (value `1`) is excluded